# Realm Android sync and async queries different results

Tags: android, realm

I'm facing this in my app, 2 consequent queries, the first sync and the second async return me different results

```
try (Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()) {
    App appRealm = realm.where(App.class).findFirst();
    RealmList<CookieRealm> cookies0 = appRealm.getCookies(); <--Here cookies0 size is 0

    realm.where(App.class).findFirstAsync().<App>asObservable()
            .filter(app -> app.isLoaded())
            .first()
            .subscribe(app -> {
                    RealmList<CookieRealm> cookies = app.getCookies(); <--Here cookies size is 2
            });
    }
```

How could it be possible? There is something wrong with the queries?

Realm version is 2.1.1

Comment: Are you writing things in the background at the same time?

Comment: There is a writing operation but the log indicate it terminate before the first query in the above code. It is possible that the async writing operation take a while to complete after the setter is called?

Comment: There is no setter in the above code, so not sure what you mean, but if a write happened on another thread, your thread will not be updated until the next looper event. So even though the log say it is done, your query might not find it, but the async one will, because it run on the "latest" version.